# Printing every other line from input text

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I am trying to do some text manipulation in *Mathematica*. After importing a text file (`in.txt`) as a string, how would you then output every other line? In the command line using `awk` for instance one would do

```
awk 'NR % 9 != 8' in.txt
```

However, after looking through the documentation *Mathematica* doesn't seem to have any current line number querying mechanism. Do you need to split the input string on every new line and then work with the list of strings? Or is *Mathematica* not the best choice for manipulating text?

Comment: There is a mistake in you awk's code: it should be `awk 'NR % 2!=0' file.txt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could fashion yourself a tool, for instance the following:

```
printlines[filename_, start_: 1, end_: All, every_: 1] := Module[
  {lines},
  lines = MapIndexed[
     {First@#2, #1} &,
     ReadList[filename, "String"]
    ];
  Grid[lines[[start ;; end ;; every]], Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}]
]
```

You can pass a filename to open, and option arguments to specify the first and last lines to print, and the "pitch" (i.e. printing every 2nd, 3rd, ... line). For instance:

```
file = "what's in a name.txt";
printlines[file]
```

[image: Juliet's monologue]

```
printlines[file, 6, 7]
```

[image: only the punchline]

```
printlines[file, 6, All, 3]
```

[image: every three lines]

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` approach you gave as an example is fundamentally different to what you ask. With `awk` you do some text processing ON THE FLY (at the same time each line is read), it is not equivalent to 1/read ALL the text first, then 2/ do the filtering, processing on the whole text saved in memory. These involve completely different strategies.

You can actually do something similar to `awk` in Mathematica using [Low level functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelFileOperations.html):

To read every other line **on the fly**, you can do for example:

```
(* Here is the way to create the dummy file, "file.txt", example I use in the test:
Table["Blabla # "<>ToString[i]<>"\n", {i, 10}]//StringJoin//Export["file.txt", #] &
*)


stream = OpenRead["file.txt"];

NestWhileList[
 (Skip[stream, Record]; Read[stream, Record])&,
 (Read[stream, Record]),
 # =!= EndOfFile &,
 1, Infinity, -1]

Close[stream]
```

> `{"Blabla # 1", "Blabla # 3", "Blabla # 5", "Blabla # 7", "Blabla # 9"}`

In case you don't know, it is also possible to run directly from Mathematica the awk's code (or some other external command) and retrieve the result, for example here:

```
ReadList["!awk 'NR % 2!=0' file.txt", String]
```

> `{"Blabla # 1", "Blabla # 3", "Blabla # 5", "Blabla # 7", "Blabla # 9"}`